# Calculate the probability of one set to be covered by random subsets

Tags: algorithm, set

Suppose these two sets are given as **input**:

- One set *U* as universe
- And one set *S* containing some of the subsets of *U*.

The members of *S* are assigned with *random* flags 0 or 1. For each member of *S*, the probability of flag 1 is *p* and flag 0 is *(1-p)*.

The desired **output** is: The probability of 'Union of the flag 1 subsets in *S* = *U*'

Although considering all the possible combinations of the flag 1 subsets in *S* is the trivial algorithm to lead to output, the running time of this brute force method is obviously exponential.

Is there any polynomial time algorithm which leads to the exact or approximate output? Or can we reduce the problem to any famous one like set-cover?

Comment: Isn't that exactly set cover? You need to find all combinations of subsets that produce U. Once you have them, you can calculate the probability.

Comment: It is very similar, but not exactly the same. Set cover finds the minimum covering group of subsets. I’m looking for all the covering group of subsets to calculate the average probability. I wonder if it was possible to solve this recursively! Do u know any derivatives of set cover that is closer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Getting an exact answer is #P-hard (counting analog of NP, thus at least as hard), since this problem generalizes monotone 2-CNF-SAT, which is known to be #P-hard (Welsh, Dominic; Gale, Amy (2001), "The complexity of counting problems", Aspects of complexity: minicourses in algorithmics, complexity and computational algebra: mathematics workshop, Kaikoura, January 7–15, 2000, pp. 115ff, Theorem 57.). The reduction is to set U to the set of clause identifiers and let each subset in S be the set of clauses in which some variable appears. EDIT: set p = 1/2 for each set, natch.

Comment: Thanks, do u have any idea for approximate solution?

Comment: You mentioned it is counting problem. But I doubt if taking average necessarily needs counting! If the average value can be updated at each iteration it can be modelled by dynamic algorithms.

Comment: @MehdiJafarizadeh Multiply the probability by 2^number_of_sets to get a count.